# blank page with " [ ] " node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes

I've been trying to set up a new route "Dashboard", and for some reason after I started working on its Schema whenever I try to get to websiteName/dashboard it shows me a blank page with "[ ]". I have no idea what's going on.

Here are my routes:

```
const dashboardController = require('./controllers/dashboard');
app.get('/dashboard', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, dashboardController.getDashboard);
app.post('/dashboard', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, dashboardController.postCreateTodo);
```

dashboard.js inside controllers folder:

```
const async = require('async');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('../models/User');
const Todo = require('../models/Dashboard');

/**
 * GET /dashboard
 * 
 */

exports.getDashboard = function(req, res){
  Todo.find({userId: req.user.id}, function (err, todos) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    res.send(todos);
  });
};

/**
* POST /dashboard
* 
*/
exports.postCreateTodo = (req, res, next) => {
  User.create(req.body.todo, function(err, newTodo){
      if(err){
          res.render("new");
      } else {
          //then, redirect to the index
          res.redirect("/dashboard");
      }
  });
};
```

Dashboard.js inside models folder:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/User');

const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, default : ''},
  User: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  createdAt  : {type : Date, default : Date.now}

});

const Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', todoSchema);
module.exports = Todo;
```

And finally dashboard.jade:

```
extends ../layout

block additionalCSS
  link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='assets/css/todos.css')
  link(href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,500', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
  link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href=' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css')
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lemonade/2.1.0/lemonade.min.css')
  script(type='text/javascript', src='assets/plugins/jquery-3.0.0.min.js')


block content
  #container
    .page-header
      h3 Dashboard
    .frame
      .bit-2
        h1
          | Do 
          i.fa.fa-plus                      
        input(type='text', placeholder='Add New Todo')             
        ul
          li
            span
              i.fa.fa-trash
            |  Finish Daily Report               
          li
            span
              i.fa.fa-trash
            |  House on Fire              
          li
            span
              i.fa.fa-trash
            |  Crying Baby          
      .bit-2
        h1
          | Decide 
          i.fa.fa-plus             
        input(type='text', placeholder='Add New Todo')            
        ul
          li
            span
              i.fa.fa-trash
            |  Exercising              
          li
            span
              i.fa.fa-trash
            |  Calling Family And Friends             
          li
            span
              i.fa.fa-trash
            |  Long-term Biz Strategy
    |         
    .frame
      .bit-2
        h1
          | Delegate 
          i.fa.fa-plus             
        input(type='text', placeholder='Add New Todo')            
        ul
          li
            span
              i.fa.fa-trash
            |  Scheduling Interviews              
          li
            span
              i.fa.fa-trash
            |  Booking Flights               
          li
            span
              i.fa.fa-trash
            |  Answering Certain emails          
      .bit-2
        h1
          | Delete 
          i.fa.fa-plus            
        input(type='text', placeholder='Add New Todo')             
        ul
          li
            span
              i.fa.fa-trash
            |  Watching Television             
          li
            span
              i.fa.fa-trash
            |  Checking Social Media               
          li
            span
              i.fa.fa-trash
            |  Surfing The Web

block additionalJS  
script(type='text/javascript', src='assets/js/todos.js')
```

Note: I have not finished adding in the form and values to dashboard.jade from the schema for the CRUD requests

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks for taking your time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not rendering your `dashboard.jade` view, you're currently just responding to the GET request with JSON (`res.send(todos)`).

My guess is you meant to do `res.render('dashboard', { todos: todos })` or something similar instead of `res.send(todos)`.

Also, on an unrelated note, you're not respoding to GET requests when `Todo.find()` fails with an error. You should at least respond with `res.send(500)` or something to indicate an internal error to the client.

Comment: Thank you so much! That had been bothering me for three whole days. I'm still a noob :)